# How do I download the os x command line tools without downloading xcode?

Tags: xcode

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I know, at some point, they were available for download from the apple developer website, but this no longer seems to be available. Is there no longer a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Apple's developer downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Sign in (or register if necessary).

Find “Command Line Tools” in the list.  Click it to show the download link.  Click the download link.

As of this writing, the second item in the list is “Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - September 2013”.  (The first item, “Bug Reporter Logging Profiles  (iOS)”, is open by default is rather tall, so you'll probably need to close it or scroll down.)

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for your help. I have the same first item as you, but for whatever reason the 2nd item in the list for me is "Kernel Debug Kit 10.6.8 build 10K549". I think I will try creating a new account and see if that fixes it.

Comment: welp, I signed in with a different account and it was available to me using that other account. It's beyond me why that was happening, thanks again for your help!